# Pandas divide by value not giving correct result

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe 'pivoted' :

```
Reason                CE CS DG DR IC  IO    
Warehouse Month                                                                
01        01           9  4  4  0  1   8
```

I also have a variable that accumulates the total of the issues.  It's an "int" type variable.  In this case it is 626

When I run the following line:  `total_percentages = pivoted/total_issues`

I'm not getting the correct (or expected) results:

```
01        01     0.021143  0.009397  0.009397  0.000000  0.002349  0.018793
```

I would expect this:

```
01        01     0.014376  0.006389 0.006389  0.00000   0.001597  0.012780
```

My full code:

```
issue_df = pd.read_sql(issue_query, cnxn)
issue_df.rename(columns={'00001' : 'Invoices', 'OBWHID' : 'Warehouse', 'OBRTRC':'Reason', 'INV_MONTH':'Month', '00005':'Date'}, inplace=True)


pivoted = pd.pivot_table(issue_df, index=["Warehouse", "Month"], values=["Invoices"], columns=['Reason'], aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)

pivoted.loc['Column Total'] = pivoted.sum()
print(pivoted.dtypes)

#Percentages of Warehouse Returns by Month
warehouse_percentages = pivoted[:] = 100 * pivoted[:].div(pivoted[:].sum(axis=1), axis=0)
print(warehouse_percentages)
print(total_issues)
total_percentages = pivoted.div(total_issues)`
```

Comment: what is `pivoted.dtypes` giving you?

Comment: did you try pivoted.div(total_issues)?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga int64 looks to be the data type.

Comment: @A-Za-z I did try as you suggested and got the same results.

Comment: @Mitch I'm not sure what other information you need, I'd be happy to supply anything you think may help

Comment: The multi-index dataframe can not be reproduced using read_clipboard. Hence it becomes difficult to test the solution. For eg, I tried .div() in a sample multi-index dataframe and it works fine

Comment: @AlliDeacon What I mean is that whatever your issue is is not contained in the question. So something is happening that you're not including here.

Comment: You're certain that `total_issues` is 626 here? And not, say, 425.68?

Comment: @Mitch that is what the print statement showed: `total issues = 626`

Comment: @AlliDeacon And where are you printing `pivoted` before the operation?

Comment: @Mitch I changed my print to print the dtypes.  So the 5th line is where it was previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the line

```
warehouse_percentages = pivoted[:] = 100 * pivoted[:].div(pivoted[:].sum(axis=1), axis=0)
```

you are re-assigning all of the values of `pivoted` to be the result of the right hand side of the operation, which is why your expected output isn't matching what you print `pivoted` as before the line above.

Thus, if you don't *intend* on modifying `pivoted` with this operation, remove `pivoted[:]` - I'm not sure if you think that without the copy you'll modify `pivoted` but it is not necessary - Pandas operations almost always by default do not operate in place, but return another object.

```
warehouse_percentages = 100* pivoted.div(pivoted.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  As a pandas beginner and Python, "fly by the seat of my pants-er" I appreciate your input and now find it painfully obvious.  You are my hero of the day!

Comment: @AlliDeacon You're very welcome, glad I could help :)